# How to set table width in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

When a table is created in a Google Docs file, it is full width, stretching from one margin to another. I have created some tables, then amended the margins and created a few more. That has left me with tables of differing widths.

I could re-size them individually, but that would be a pain. Is there a way to set a table's width (or all tables) to 100% of the space between the margins with a script? I can't find an object for tablewidth, there's plenty of info on columnwidth, but that's not the approach I wish to take.

I have read the post *Google Apps Script - Chart Service: table size, column format* but, again, that's not what I am trying to do.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAS does have access to the 'Table' object. [GAS-tablewidth](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#setColumnWidth(Integer,Number))

You can set the width of individual columns, not the table as a whole.